# Compressing hexadecimal data in PHP from bin2hex function

Tags: php

Could we compress hexadecimal string using gzencode?

Below is my code snippet. Doesn't seem to work. There's no error too.

```
$final_code = bin2hex( $final_code );
$final_code = gzencode($final_code, 9);
return $final_code;
```

Comment: Could this be the answer? https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33737/is-it-better-to-encrypt-before-compression-or-vice-versa

Comment: Doubling the amount of data before compressing makes no sense.

Comment: I have to generate a QR code thus I need to convert my data from binary to alphanumeric representation. Unless you have a better ideal, Sir.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. The hex encoding doubles the amount of data, the base64 encoding only increases the data by 33%.